# Open a new tab in the running instance of Windows Terminal from CLI

Tags: windows-terminal

Is there a way to open a new tab in a running instance of Windows Terminal from CLI and make it point to a specific folder?

Every time I run `wt.exe -d c:\my-folder` it opens a new window.

Answer (score 20):

Now, we have this option in Windows Terminal's Settings.

[image]

Comment: This does not work from the CLI as the OP asks. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows): *This will always open a new window. Windows Terminal is not yet capable of opening new tabs or panes in an existing instance.*

Comment: This now works from the CLI as the OP asks.

Comment: Not working in administrator mode.

Answer (score 15):

If someone needs the commands to create a new tab (and not open a new window) from a context menu item:
(if you are already in the directory):

```bash
wt -w 0 nt
```

(and if you click on the directory):

```bash
wt -w 0 nt -d %1
```

(to open in the current directory):

```bash
wt -w 0 nt -d %CD%
```

You can add these commands in the respective registry of each item (or in a new one)

Source: the GitHub discussion in the other answer.

if you run that in cmd or a script, it launches a new instance if none already running, or adds a tab if there is a running instance.

Comment: Not working in administrator mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is an outstanding issue that is going to get fixed eventually: [Add support for wt.exe to run commands in an existing Terminal Window #4472](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/4472)

Comment: The issue has been closed and a PR was merged, so the feature should be in the next Windows Terminal Preview soon :)

Answer (score 0):

No, as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows), calling `wt.exe`

*...will always open a new window. Windows Terminal is not yet capable of opening new tabs or panes in an existing instance.*

Comment: This answer is no longer true after recent releases (details in other answers).

Answer (score -1):

You can the tool [**neWin**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newin), a CLI command that opens new Window(s) or Tab(s) on WSL Windows Terminal (or KDE Konsole on native linux) and executes given bash command(s).

```
$ newin --workdir ~/myproject 'npm run start' 'npm run test:watch'

# executes each command in a separate new window and exit.
```

It runs on nodejs, works great on package.json scripts, but can also be used in any environment/platform.

(disclaimer: I'm the author of neWin)